# Save before closing python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a GUI with Tkinter at the moment. With the GUI I can create files, add certain lines to the files, delete lines, save and load files. My problem is, that i want to prevent the closing of the window if the current file wasn't saved.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is totally possible (unless perhaps the process is being terminated abruptly), by making use of [`WM_DELETE_WINDOW`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) protocol:

> *...The most commonly used protocol is called WM_DELETE_WINDOW, and is used to define what happens when the user explicitly closes a window
>   using the window manager.*